# session_start( ) not working in firefox and operamini but works fine in microsoft edge browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am unable to have my scripts open in firefox and operamini when using session_start(). On firefox, it shows the error (Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to localhost. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR), then on operamini it shows the error (This site can’t be reached. The connection was reset.). Everything works fine with microsoft edge browser. This is my first challenge since I started PHP Object Oriented Programming practice. The other projects I developed with the PHP procedural approach works just fine on every browser.
Your assistance is much appreciated.

The code below is a php script class I call loginClass()

```
<?php
    class userLogin
    {
        private $servername = "localhost";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $databasename = "receipt";
        public $con;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->con = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->databasename, 3307);
            if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
             trigger_error("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }else{
            return $this->con;
            }
        }
        
        public function register($post)
        {
            session_start();
            //validate username
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['uname'])))
            {
                $uname = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
            }
            //validate fullname
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])))
            {
                $name = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            }
            //validate country
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['country'])))
            {
                $country = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
            }
            //validate state
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['state'])))
            {
                $state = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
            }
            //validate address
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['adrs'])))
            {
                $adrs = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['adrs']);
            }
            //validate city
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['city'])))
            {
                $city = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
            }
            //validate email
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])))
            {
                $email = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            }
            //validate phone number
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['phone'])))
            {
                $phone = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
            }
            //validate password
            if($this->con->real_escape_string(strlen($_POST['pass'])<6))
            {
                    $passerr = "error1";
            }else{
                $pass = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
            }
            //validate confirm password
            if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['cpass'])))
            {
                $cpass = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['cpass']);
                if($cpass != $pass){
                    $cpasserr = "error2";
                }
            }

            if($passerr == "error1"){
                    header("Location:userregister.php?msg3=paserr");
                        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                        $_SESSION['country'] = $country;
                        $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
                        $_SESSION['adrs'] = $adrs;
                        $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                        $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
            }elseif($cpasserr == "error2"){
                    header("Location:userregister.php?msg4=pasmis");
                        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                        $_SESSION['country'] = $country;
                        $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
                        $_SESSION['adrs'] = $adrs;
                        $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                        $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
            }else{
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO usertbl(Username, Fullname, Country, State, Address, City, Email, PhoneNumber, Password)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $puname, $pname, $pcountry, $pstate, $padrs, $pcity, $pemail, $pphoneno, $ppass);
                    $puname = $uname;
                    $pname = $name;
                    $pcountry = $country;
                    $pstate = $state;
                    $padrs = $adrs;
                    $pcity = $city;
                    $pemail = $email;
                    $pphoneno = $phone;
                    $ppass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    if(!$this->con->error){
                        header("Location:userlogin.php?msg1=success");
                        $_SESSION['uname'] = $puname;
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $pname;
                        $_SESSION['country'] = $pcountry;
                        $_SESSION['state'] = $pstate;
                        $_SESSION['adrs'] = $padrs;
                        $_SESSION['city'] = $pcity;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $pemail;
                        $_SESSION['phone'] = $pphoneno;
                    }else{
                        header("Location:userregister.php?msg2=failed");
                        $_SESSION['uname'] = $puname;
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $pname;
                        $_SESSION['country'] = $pcountry;
                        $_SESSION['state'] = $pstate;
                        $_SESSION['adrs'] = $padrs;
                        $_SESSION['city'] = $pcity;
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $pemail;
                        $_SESSION['phone'] = $pphoneno;
                    }
                }
            }

            public function login($postlogin)
            {
                session_start();
                if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['uname'])))
                {
                    $uname = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
                }
                //validate password
                if(!empty($this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass'])))
                {
                    $pass = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
                }
                    $sql = "SELECT Username, Fullname, Country, State, Address, City, Email, PhoneNumber, Password FROM usertbl WHERE Username = ?";
                    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $puname);
                    $puname = $uname;
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
                    if($num_rows>0)
                    {
                        $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
                        $uname = $rows['Username'];
                        $name = $rows['Fullname'];
                        $country = $rows['Country'];
                        $state = $rows['State'];
                        $adrs = $rows['Address'];
                        $city = $rows['City'];
                        $email = $rows['Email'];
                        $pnum = $rows['PhoneNumber'];
                        $spass = $rows['Password'];

                        if(!password_verify($pass, $spass))
                        {
                            header('location: userLogin.php?logerr1=passerr');
                            $_SESSION['lname'] = $uname;
                            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                            $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
                            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                            $_SESSION['country'] = $country;
                            $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
                            $_SESSION['adrs'] = $adrs;
                            $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
                            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                            $_SESSION['pnum'] = $pnum;
                            header('location: userdbboard.php?login=success');
                        }
                    }else{
                            header('location: userLogin.php?logerr2=nouser');
                            $_SESSION['lname'] = $uname;
                            $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
                    }
            }

    }
```

This is my HTML Login Form

```
<?php
        session_start();
        //header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        //header("Pragma: no-cache");

    include 'loginClass.php';

    $login = new userLogin();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $login->login($_POST);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="receipt.css?v=<?php echo time();?>">
    <script rel="javascript" src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <?php
        //error_reporting(0);
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function passFunction()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("pass");
        if (x.type === "password")
        {
        x.type = "text";
        }
        else
        {
        x.type = "password";
        }
    } 
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cpassFunction()
        {
            var y = document.getElementById('cpass');
            if(y.type === "password")
            {
                y.type = "text";
            }
            else
            {
                y.type = "password";
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
        <!--Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light" style="background-color:darkgrey" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <label class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/buy.png" width="20" height="20"><b>  RECEIPT GENERATING SYSTEM (RGS)</b></label>

            <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="receipthome.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav><br><br>
    <div class="container h-100" style="border-radius:5px; padding:1rem">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6"  style="border:1px solid grey; border-radius:5px; padding:1rem;">
            <form class="" style="height:100%; padding:1rem;" method="POST" action="userlogin.php">
            <h4 class="#">Sign in
            <label class="label" style="float:right" style="font-size:10px;">Don't have an account yet? 
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float:right;" href="userregister.php"><b>Register</b></a>
            </label>
            </h4><br>
            <?php
                if (isset($_GET['msg1']) == "success") {
                echo "<div id='myView' class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
                <span type='button' id='modalClose' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' style='float:right' title='Hide this box'>X</span>
                Registration successfull. Login below.
            </div>";
                }
                elseif (isset($_GET['logerr1']) == "passerr") {
                echo "<div id='myView' class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>
                <span type='button' id='modalClose' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' style='float:right' title='Hide this box'>X</span>
                Oops! Invalid password.
            </div>";
                }
                elseif(isset($_GET['logerr2']) == "nouser"){
                echo "<div id='myView' class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>
                <span type='button' id='modalClose' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' style='float:right' title='Hide this box'>X</span>
                User does not exist. Are you sure you have an account?
            </div>";
                }
            ?>
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uname']; ?>" required></input>
        </div><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cpass">Password</label>
            <label class="lpass" for="chk" style="float:right">show password</label>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="chk" style="float:right;" onclick="cpassFunction()"></input><br>
            <input id="cpass" class="form-control" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" value="<?php //echo $_SESSION['pass']; ?>" required></input>
        </div><br>
        <input class="btn btn-outline-primary" aria-pressed="true" style="float:right" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></input>
    </div>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#modalClose').on('click', function () {
            $('#myView').hide();
        })
    })
</script>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
            <a href="receipthome.php">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <p>Barna_Be &copy; 2021 All rights reserved. <b>BnB SoftTech</p>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting in Firefox and other browsers?

Comment: you have session_start in multiple places, thats not going to work

Comment: Please give more details about the error - what is it referring to? Does Firefox refuse to load the complete page, or is this something you see in console, referring to one of the assets (scripts, stylesheets, images) the page tries to embed? Are you testing this locally, or “online” on a publicly reachable webserver? Are you using an SSL certificate and access this via HTTPS?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the error message from firefox and operamini. I'm testing it locally through localhost. Thanks.

Comment: can you please check if any antivirus or extension is intercepting secure connection ? Also, check if the URL is with www or without www because it consider 2 different sessions for both. in this case rewrite all urls to www from .htaccess

Comment: Where is this .htacess? @ShaikhAejazAhmed

Comment: It should be on your server along with other files. 
It starts with dot(.) so it may be hidden or connect to server via FTP & check